# Alter namespace prefixing with ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree

By default, when you call ElementTree.parse(someXMLfile) the Python ElementTree library prefixes every parsed node with it's namespace URI in Clark's Notation:

```
    {http://example.org/namespace/spec}mynode
```

This makes accessing specific nodes by name a huge pain later in the code.

I've read through the docs on ElementTree and namespaces and it looks like the `iterparse()` function should allow me to alter the way the parser prefixes namespaces, but for the life of me I can't actually make it change the prefix. It seems like that may happen in the background before the ns-start event even fires as in this example:

```
for event, elem in iterparse(source):
    if event == "start-ns":
        namespaces.append(elem)
    elif event == "end-ns":
        namespaces.pop()
    else:
        ...
```

How do I make it change the prefixing behavior and what is the proper thing to return when the function ends?

Comment: interesting. I would love to know too. The way I proceed is by creating "constant" XHTML_NS = '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}' and then using in the code XHTML_NS+"mynode"

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve? Why is Clark's notation a huge pain?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate with existing code that accesses things by their original prefix (i.e. `openSearch`, rather than `{http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/}`) and I was hoping there was a nicer way than building the type of prefix map that @karlcow mentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't specifically need to use `iterparse`. Instead, the following script:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

NS_MAP = {
    'http://www.red-dove.com/ns/abc' : 'rdc',
    'http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml' : 'mx',
    'http://www.red-dove.com/ns/def' : 'oth',
}

DATA = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdc:container xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                 xmlns:rdc="http://www.red-dove.com/ns/abc"
                 xmlns:oth="http://www.red-dove.com/ns/def">
  <mx:Style>
    <oth:style1/>
  </mx:Style>
  <mx:Style>
    <oth:style2/>
  </mx:Style>
  <mx:Style>
    <oth:style3/>
  </mx:Style>
</rdc:container>'''

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(DATA))
some_node = tree.getroot().getchildren()[1]
print ET.fixtag(some_node.tag, NS_MAP)
some_node = some_node.getchildren()[0]
print ET.fixtag(some_node.tag, NS_MAP)
```

produces

```
('mx:Style', None)
('oth:style2', None)
```

Which shows how you can access the fully-qualified tag names of individual nodes in a parsed tree. You should be able to adapt this to your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

xml.etree.ElementTree doesn't appear to have fixtag, well, not according to the documentation. However I've looked at some source code for fixtag and you do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(inFile, events=("start", "end")):
    namespace, looktag = string.split(elem.tag[1:], "}", 1)
```

You have the tag string in looktag, suitable for a lookup. The namespace is in namespace.

Comment: In my Python 2.6.5, xml.etree.ElementTree has a fixtag function, but xml.etree.cElementTree does not.