# Parsing RSS with Elementtree in Python

Tags: python, xml, rss, elementtree

How do you search for namespace-specific tags in XML using Elementtree in Python?

I have an XML/RSS document like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.0/"
>
<channel>
    <title>sometitle</title>
    <pubDate>Tue, 28 Aug 2012 22:36:02 +0000</pubDate>
    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=2.5.1</generator>
    <language>en</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.0</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:category><wp:category_nicename>apache</wp:category_nicename><wp:category_parent></wp:category_parent><wp:cat_name><![CDATA[Apache]]></wp:cat_name></wp:category>
</channel>
</rss>
```

But when I try and find all "wp:category" tags by doing:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
tree = xml.parse(fn)
doc = tree.getroot()
categories = doc.findall('channel/wp:category')
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'wp' not found in prefix map
```

Searching for any non-namespace specific fields works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [handle the namespace prefixes](https://web.archive.org/web/20200322132918/http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm), either by using iterparse and handling the event directly or by explicitly declaring the prefixes you're interested in before parsing. Depending on what you're trying to do, I will admit in my lazier moments I just strip all the prefixes out with a string replace before parsing the XML.

EDIT: [this similar question might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249876/alter-namespace-prefixing-with-elementtree-in-python)

Comment: This makes no sense. The namespace prefixes are defined in the parent <rss> tag. I shouldn't have to pre-parse my RSS document just so I can spoon-feed the namespaces to my RSS parser...

Comment: I'm not arguing with you, I'm just saying that's how I got around it.