# elementtree register namespace error

Tags: python, elementtree

I tried to register namespace with this:

```
ET.register_namespace("inv", "http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd")
```

but it doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tutorial\temp_xml2.py", line 34, in module>
    for listInvoice in root.findall('inv:invoiceHeader'):
  File "C:\Python27\LIB\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 390, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python27\LIB\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 293, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "C:\Python27\LIB\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 259, in iterfind
    token = next()
  File "C:\Python27\LIB\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 83, in xpath_tokenizer
    raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix)
SyntaxError: prefix 'inv' not found in prefix map
>>>
```

what's wrong with this?

---

Thanks Martinj

I tried - 1.:

```
for listInvoice in root.findall('inv:invoiceHeader', namespaces=dict(inv='http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd')):
    invoiceHeader = listInvoice.find('inv:id', namespaces=dict(inv='http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd')).text
    print invoiceHeader
```

Result: (empty)

2.:

```
nsmap=root.nsmap
print nsmap
```

Result: AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'nsmap'

3.:

```
for listInvoice in root.findall('.//{http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd}invoiceHeader'):
    invoiceHeader = listInvoice.find('.//{http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd}id').text
    print invoiceHeader
```

Result: Works ok.

Is there any chance to register namespaces at once? Then I would like to use listInvoice.find('inv:id').text instead of listInvoice.find('.//{http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd}id').text (nicer code and easy to read)

Comment: This answer looks pretty similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861866/735204

Answer (score 19):

It looks like the documentation hasn't been updated on how to use namespaces and `.findall()`.

The `.findall()` function (as well as `.find()`, `.findtext() and`.iterfind()`) takes a`namespaces` argument which is supposed to be a mapping. That is the only structure consulted when finding tags:

```
root.findall('inv:invoiceHeader', namespaces=dict(inv='http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd'))
```

The `.register_namespace()` function is only useful for when serializing a tree out to text again.

Comment: Thanks, this works! For `.get()` I needed to prefix with `{namespace-URL}`, e.g. `element.get({http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}ID)`.

Comment: @Vincent: yes, attribute access has no support for namespace prefix translation and you need to pass in the fully qualified namespace prefix.